# MIPS: arrays are not printing correctly

Tags: arrays, floating-point, mips

So, I'm inputting two arrays and printing one of them (for now), but when I go to print one of the arrays, it prints some values of one and some values of the other array. I have no idea why this would happen. Please help. Here's my code, followed by an example output:

```
.data

    title: .asciiz "Find The Product of Two Matrices\n\n"
    menuString: .asciiz "Menu\n\n"
    option1: .asciiz "1. Enter values and find product\n"
    option2: .asciiz "2. Exit program\n\n"
    inputString: .asciiz "Enter selection: "

    promptSize: .asciiz "\nEnter row size of square matrix: "
    promptRow: .asciiz "Row: "
    promptCol: .asciiz "Col: "
    promptMatrix1Float: .asciiz "Enter a first matrix's float: "
    promptMatrix2Float: .asciiz "Enter a second matrix's float: "
    answer: .asciiz " Answer:"
    printFloat: .asciiz "\nA Float: "
    inputFirstMatrix: .asciiz "\n\nInput First Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):\n\n"
        inputSecondMatrix: .asciiz "\n\nInput Second Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):\n\n"


.globl main
.text

################################### INPUT SIZE AND MATRICES ####################


size:  li $v0, 4
       la $a0, promptSize
       syscall

        li, $v0, 5
    syscall



       add $t1, $v0, $v0
       li $t0, 0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputFirstMatrix
    syscall

L1: beq $t0, $t1, L2IndexInit

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptMatrix1Float
    syscall

        li $v0, 6                      #6 is the syscall code for get float
        syscall 

        sll $t3, $t0,  3
    add $t3, $a2, $t3
    s.d $f0, 0($t3)         # Store $f0 at memory location .


    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    j L1 

L2IndexInit:


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputSecondMatrix
    syscall

        li $t0, 0


L2: beq $t0, $t1, PrintIndexInit

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptMatrix2Float
    syscall

        li $v0, 6                      #6 is the syscall code for get float
        syscall 

        sll $t3, $t0,  3
    add $t3, $a1, $t3
    s.d $f0, 0($t3)         # Store $f0 at memory location .


    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    j L2 

############################## PRINT MATRIX ################################################# 

PrintIndexInit:  
     li $t0, 0

PrintMatrix:   beq $t0, $t1, End

      sll $t4, $t0, 3
      add $t4, $a2, $t4
      l.d $f12, 0($t4)

      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, printFloat
      syscall

      li $v0, 2                      #2 is the syscall code for print float (arg. to print in f12)
      syscall

      addi $t0, $t0, 1

      j PrintMatrix






####################################### MAIN FUNCTION AND END ######################

End:
     lw $ra, 0($sp)
     addi $sp, $sp, 4
     jr $ra




main:
    li $v0, 4   
    la $a0, title
    syscall


        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        jal size
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

---

example output:

```
Find The Product of Two Matrices


Enter row size of square matrix: 2


Input First Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):

Enter a first matrix's float: 2.3
Enter a first matrix's float: 4.3
Enter a first matrix's float: 6.5
Enter a first matrix's float: 4.3


Input Second Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):

Enter a second matrix's float: 3.2
Enter a second matrix's float: 6.5
Enter a second matrix's float: 8.9
Enter a second matrix's float: 3.2

A Float: 6.50000000
A Float: 8.89999962
A Float: 3.20000005
A Float: 4.30000019
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems with the code that made it not run:

- No space allocated for the two matrices -- use `syscall 9` to allocate space on the heap
- In `End`, you're popping the return address from the stack, but the address you need is already in `$ra`

After fixing these to make it run, the code works fine. Here's how I allocated the memory in `size`:

```
size:  
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptSize
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    add $t1, $v0, $v0

    sll $a0, $t1, 3
    li $v0, 9
    syscall
    move $a2, $v0

    li $v0, 9
    syscall
    move $a1, $v0

    li $t0, 0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputFirstMatrix
    syscall
```

`End` and `main`:

```
End:
    jr $ra

main:
    li $v0, 4   
    la $a0, title
    syscall

        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        jal size

        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 4

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Output:

```
Find The Product of Two Matrices


Enter row size of square matrix: 2


Input First Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):

Enter a first matrix's float: 1.2
Enter a first matrix's float: 3.4
Enter a first matrix's float: 5.6
Enter a first matrix's float: 7.8


Input Second Matrix(left-to-right and top-to-bottom):

Enter a second matrix's float: 2.1
Enter a second matrix's float: 4.3
Enter a second matrix's float: 6.5
Enter a second matrix's float: 8.7

A Float: 1.2
A Float: 3.4
A Float: 5.6
A Float: 7.8
```